# Display specific post format with limit number of post

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, format

I create a loop in Wordpress with the condition like this:

1. Display a specific post format (example: video)
2. Limiting the post number. In this case, I only want to display 2 posts.

Here my code:

```
 <?php $i = 1; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts() && $i < 3) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php get_template_part( 'content-video', get_post_format() ); ?>
 <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
 <?php else : ?>
 <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

I already have file name content-video.php.

Unfortunately, the loop does not work. Only displayed the first post, not a specific post (video post format) with template from content-video.php.

Appreciate for any help, or alternative code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My remarks about your code:

1. I think you have bad wrapping for `if else while` statements. You are missing an `endif` at the end in the case your approach is correct.
2. Why use inside your code the `i` variable since you can customize any query in WP, especially for number of post using the parameter `posts_per_page`.
3. Why not to use the loop inside `content-video.php`  and write only:`get_template_part('content-video', get_post_format());` Like in `single.php and loop-single.php` the themes provided with wordpress installation (twenty themes) .

Good luck

Comment: Look like a great idea for number 3. I will try. Thank you.

Comment: Not at all, please to give a feedback when this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be to get posts of "video" post format from a query, but I'm not sure how:)

As a workaround you could do this inside the loop:

```
 if (!has_post_format('video'))
   continue;
```

Comment: The code display the first post from any post format. I want to display only video post format to display.

Comment: I updated the answer, its not the most efficient way, but it should wok.